# Launch a Bluetooth Low Energy command after raspberry startup

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi-os, systemd, systemd-startup

I wrote a command in `swift` that uses the internal bluetooth low energy module of my `Raspberry PI 4`. This command must be launched as superuser.
Everything works perfectly if I launch the executable from the terminal, but I'm struggling to make it launch automatically after the system startup.
I'm trying to use the `systemd`, following this [guide](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/how-to-run-a-raspberry-pi-program-on-startup) . I've created my `punch.service` inside the `/lib/systemd/system/` and followed the step to enable it. The software is running after startup and I can tell it because I'm also using the GPIO to command some leds, but the raspberry doesn't seems to advertise and is not available to accept connections.
If I kill the process and launch the executable again it starts to advertise too.
My service file looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Punch service
After=bluetooth.target
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/pi/Desktop/RaspberryBLE/PunchBLE/.build/release/RaspberryBLE

[Install]
WantedBy=bluetooth.target
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I suppose that this will tell the system to launch the executable after bluetooth service are up and running, but it doesn't seems so.
Doesn't matter if startup the raspberry on desktop or CLI with autologin.
Am I missing something? Is there a way to make it sure that my service is launched as last?

Comment: BTW -- I know you already have an accepted answer, so this is more of an "in future" -- you can get some information about what happened with a service via `systemctl status [service name sans '.service']`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`systemd` will give you some flexibility, but if you want to get something running right away - while you fiddle with `systemd` - you might consider a `cron` job. Here's a simple approoach:

1. As user `pi` (or any user with `sudo` privileges, edit the `root crontab` as follows:

```bash
$ sudo crontab -e
```

2. Once the root crontab is open in your editor, add a line *similar* to this:

```
@reboot sleep 30; /path/to/your/executable >> /home/pi/mybtcronlog.txt 2>&1
```

3. Reboot to test

How it works:

1. Any job started in the `root crontab` will run as the superuser (`root`) - (*Hint: Don't ever use `sudo` in a `cron` job.*)
2. The `crontab` is simply the schedule table used by `cron` to start jobs. See `man crontab` for syntax & [crontab guru](https://crontab.guru/) if you need help with the schedule expression. `@reboot` is a special schedule, so you won't likely need any help with that.

The `crontab` entry shown above tells `cron` to run two commands sequentially:

- `sleep` for 30 seconds, and then
- run your executable bluetooth app. - give it the full path to the exe

Unlike `systemd`, `cron` has no knowledge of the status of system services<sup>NOTE</sup> required in your program. We *compensate* for that by *sleeping* for 30 seconds to give the system time to get BT started. Nothing magic about 30 secs - it may take 5 seconds, or it may take 2 minutes - depending on your system.

- `>>` is a *redirect* meaning that any text output will go to the designated file: `/home/pi/mybtcronlog.txt`
- `2>&1` redirects stderr to stdout - both streams will now appear in your log file, giving you some feedback in the event something goes wrong.

3. Run `sudo reboot` to restart your system & test your `cron` job.

---

*NOTE:* In the paradox that is systemd design logic, the `cron` daemon is actually started/controlled by a `systemd` unit. It therefore seems odd that the `systemd` designers did not provide a method to allow `cron` users to communicate their job's service dependencies. `systemd` is useful in many respects, but it can become rather complex for what would seem to be simple tasks; e.g. why can't `systemd` start `cron` as the last service during startup?

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I've tried and just by putting 60 seconds I was able to make it work!!! Weird stuff about systemd :-(

Comment: @Andrea: Yes, it's rather deep. I don't understand it well enough to explain why, but I've come to believe that designs that yield a difficult user experience are not great designs. But I suppose it's as good as we're going to get for a while.

Comment: *"In the paradox that is systemd design logic, the cron daemon is actually started/controlled by a systemd unit:* -> Yes, but there's nothing paradoxical about it because: 1) Processes cannot start themselves, 2) The kernel only starts 1 process, [init](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init), which on contemporary GNU/Linux systems is impemented by systemd. Cron runs like any other kind of background service, that's what init is for (hence it is the common ancestor of every running process, pid 1).  If it wasn't started by init/systemd, it would have to be started by something started by systemd.

Comment: *"It therefore seems odd that the systemd designers did not provide a method to allow cron users to communicate their job's service dependencies."* -> It does, to the same extent that it does for other services. Of course, that is more about the cron daemon  itself  rather than anything it starts on its own -- which **cron could** have an interface like systemd to organize tasks in a hierarchy of dependencies (or it **could** query systemd about service states), but many people would be upset if it suddenly sprouted features of that sort.

Comment: So (and I am not knocking your answer, just trying to defang some confusion about OS fundamentals), what's "paradoxical" ;) ;) is to say, "I would like a dependency based boot service like systemd, but I do not want to use systemd".  Kind of like saying you don't want to use Chrome as a web browser,  but you then gripe about how all the other web browsers don't do the things Chrome does.  A bad analogy in the sense that cron and systemd are much more dissimilar than a set of web browsers -- but note there are alternate init systems available to use (please don't act on that tho, lol).

Comment: @goldilocks: The **init** job is a tough one. I would not argue that `systemd` offers the user no advantages. What I do feel is that there's an arrogant mindset behind it; I feel it could be so much better in terms of ease of use. I also feel that if you're going to *"claim the throne"*, you should be a proper steward. Do you feel it's useful  for `systemd` to simply start `crond` at an arbitrary point, and then wash their hands of it? You're absolutely correct in that there are options available, but as hard as I try I can't convince myself to feel badly about criticizing `systemd` :)

Comment: *"Do you feel it's useful for systemd to simply start crond at an arbitrary point, and then wash their hands of it"*?  The point is not arbitrary.  Going beyond that, how should systemd control the minutiae of cron (and everything else I guess)?    Should it *read cron's config files* to find out what it is going to do, then *analyze the job specs there* and somehow determine what the prereqs for `myscript.py` are?  Well of course it could just read `myscript.py` and parse the `import` statements!  This is all so simple and obvious!

Comment: Or, going with sane convention: cron does what it does and cron is responsible for that, just like the python interpreter is responsible for what it does.  You seem to be suggesting something truly monstrous, where the only thing you would need would be the perfect omniscient init system.  If "arrogent mindset" means there's a lot of (provided) docs to read and concepts to grok regarding a very complex piece of software, then blessed be the arrogant mindset...

Comment: @goldilocks: It seems we have a difference of opinion wrt `systemd`. You are imagining I'm saying something that I'm not really... perhaps getting down to cases will help: Do you think you know enough about `systemd` to have it start `crond` as the absolute last daemon during init? I tried to do that some time ago, and never got an answer. Starting `crond` after everything else is started would cover most cases - I think. But, for some reason - `systemd` does not allow one to do this - at least not in a *straightforward* manner.

Comment: @goldilocks Your answer reflects my opinion re `systemd`: *"Can't promise this will solve your problem, but..."* I'm not knocking *your* answer either, but I feel that `systemd` demands too much from many who might otherwise benefit from its advantages. I hope that's clear - and not offensive. I hold *an opinion* re `systemd`, that's all. I feel a simpler solution may be a better solution. I never (I hope) suggest that people ignore `systemd` - that they never consider it. But *in my experience*, `systemd` usually requires far more effort than setting up a `cron` job.

Comment: I agree that setting up a cron job is easier, and if cron can do everything you want, then use cron.   I'd consider it more of an "end user" program than systemd; most linux users should never have to write a service file.   WRT getting something to run absolutely last, this is sort of a "it doesn't work that way" thing, software design largely is about going with one opinion rather than another.

Comment: ...A good reason for it *not* to work that way is: What if everyone want their service to run after (or before) **all** the others?  You need to then ask *why*, and I guarantee the answer involves an [XY problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/66378/212479) (as does your example with cron) where the X is "because it depends on ______" -- which is why IMO a dynamic hierarchy based on dependencies is a good design.  Not omnisciently perfect, of course.   BTW, a solution to "run last" (or try to) in systemd would be via a timer (see man systemd.timer), these can be in relation to boot start.

Comment: ...For the win then you just parse all the other timer files at shutdown, find the longest one, and edit yours to run that + 1 :P

Answer (score 2):

Can't promise this will solve your problem, but...

> I suppose that this will tell the system to launch the executable after bluetooth service are up and running, but it doesn't seems so

Something to keep in mind with system services is that it is very easy for the system to determine and depend upon when a service *starts*, but that is very narrowly defined in the sense that it will often be distinct from the not as simple and objectively definable "up and running" -- which may be easy to define in words for a specific service, but there are no checkpoints of that sort in general (there are some good reasons for this but I'll refrain from the tangent).

The take-away is that, in general, all the various depends/wants etc. are based on when processes *start*.  With the systemd "targets", which group services, the relationship between core services in a target does provide a bit of checkpoint-esque ordering refinement, but even without the added complication of stage 1, 2, 3 etc for every process this can be a bit delicate.

So, this seems to me wrong-headed:

```
After=bluetooth.target
After=multi-user.target
[...]
WantedBy=bluetooth.target
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

As per `man systemd.unit`:

> It is a common pattern to include a
> unit name in both the After= and Wants= options, in which case the unit listed will be started before the unit that is configured with these options.

But, as per the *Forward and reverse unit properties* table in that man page, `Wants` **is the reverse of** `WantedBy`.  So you are sort of saying that this service should start after `bluetooth.target` (and `multi-user.target`), but that this service should start when those targets start. It creates a sort of circular or non-sensical dependency.

WRT `WantedBy`, this is just what indicates where and if the service should be included when you enable it.  The simplest and most straight-forward way to use it is to just use `default.target`.  This means it will be included in the list of thing to start without nailing it down too specifically -- that can be fine tuned with dependencies on more specialized units/targets.

Obviously you need bluetooth working, and if you read through the bit on `Wants=`, `Requires=`, and `After`, something more appropriate might be:

```
[Unit]
Description=Punch service
Requires=bluetooth.service
After=bluetooth.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/pi/Desktop/RaspberryBLE/PunchBLE/.build/release/RaspberryBLE

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Notice I've used `bluetooth.service` there, not `bluetooth.target`.  This is because if you look, by default the bluetooth.target only includes one service, bluetooth.service, and since that is an actual service that starts a real executable, it is likely to be a more specific relation.

Comment: thank you for your amazing explanation that shed some light about systemd, but unfortunately didn't solve the issue